# Is normal variety over an extended field still normal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb A^n_K$ be an affine normal variety over a field $K$,  given by zero set of polynomials $F_1,...,F_r$. Let $F$ be a field extension of $K$ (let's first say it is a finite extension), then zero set of $F_1,...,F_r$ in $\mathbb A^n_F$ defines an affine variety $X_F$. The question is that is $X_F$ still a normal variety?

It is true if $X$ is isomorphic to an affine space, since affine space over any field is normal, but what in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_F$ is not necessarily normal. The concept you're after is geometrically normal: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/038L . You ought to be able to produce a counterexample using the same techniques you would to find a counterexample for a reduced scheme which is not geometrically reduced- use $K=\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ and $F=\mathbb{F}_p(T)[T^{1/p}]$.

Comment: I see, the geometric normality is the concept I am looking for. Thanks for the reference, that is a perfect dictionary!